# Определение тачскрина на устройстве

Tags: jquery, javascript

Доброго всем времени суток! Как можно определить есть ли на устройстве Тачскрин? К примеру есть какой-нибуть блок при наведении на который, что-то происходит, но на планшетах и смартфонах наведение сделать невозможно, как определять есть ли на устройстве тачскрин и в таком случае заменять hover на click.

Comment: Учите JS до тех пор, пока не станете понимать как работает JQ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/download/#-touch-shiv-cssclasses-teststyles-prefixes-load) ([docs](http://modernizr.com/docs/))

JS:

```
if( Modernizr.touch ){
    // Есть поддержка touch событий
} else {
    // ...
}
```

Или в CSS:

```
.no-touch a:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

вообще-то для тачскринов события немного другие. Не hover (такое там вообще невозможно), и не клик, а touchstart, touchend, touchmove